# edit RStudio theme tmTheme file

Tags: themes, rstudio

I made a theme based on PlasticCodeWrap theme (https://tmtheme-editor.glitch.me/#!/editor/theme/PlasticCodeWrap), but I just want to change one thing, the window used to open a files in RStudio, the actual color is dark, and I want it in light color, I just want to know the name of the variable in the code of the tmTheme file, or in the online editor, which element do I have to change ?, or how to identify the variable in the code for the window to import files.
Any Suggestion ??!!

Thanks

[image]